# Firebase - event "ecommerce_purchase" implementation

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

About the `ecommerce_purchase` event in Firebase Analytics, I'd thought about sending multiple events, one for each product bought, with the same `TRANSACTION_ID` and the value of each product. But I don't know if this would count as multiple conversions in the dashboards.

Can I do this or do I have to send only one event for each purchase? Thanks. :D

[Firebase reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.Event.html#ECOMMERCE_PURCHASE)

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be fine as long as you don't double count ecommerce_purchase events, such as one event for all and one event for each product because it will affect life time value.